# AngularJS directive to load controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I'm trying to load a controller dinamically with directive, ng-include and model params, but it's not working:

Hmtl:

```
<ng-include src="obj_data.modulo_appendice"
                dyn-controller="obj_data.modulo_appendice_controller"
                dyn-controller-url="obj_data.modulo_appendice_controller_url"></ng-include>
```

Directive:

```
WebCauApp.directive('dynControllerUrl', ['$compile', '$parse', function ($compile, $parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 200000,
        link: function (scope, elem)
        {
            // Parse the scope variable
            var controller = $parse(elem.attr('dyn-controller'))(scope);
            var controller_url = $parse(elem.attr('dyn-controller-url'))(scope);
            elem.removeAttr('dyn-controller');
            elem.removeAttr('dyn-controller-url');

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.setAttribute('src', controller_url);

            //var head = angular.element(document.querySelector('head'));
            //head.append(script);
            elem[0].parentNode.before(script);
            elem.attr('ng-controller', controller);
            $compile(elem)(scope);

        }
    }
}]);
```

error is Argument 'mycontrollername' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: where is the value `mycontrollername` coming from?  looking at this code, I would say that error message is correct: `mycontrollername` is *not* a function name;  dig in to where that value is coming from and that might reveal your problem, or give you more detail you can add to your question